# Use SetTimeOut, so messages are not sent too rapidly after one another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a small chat :)

When a user is typing (or stopped typing), this is being signalled to other users, and only when user switches between typing or not (checking if the textarea is empty or not)

Now I want to prevent those signals from being sent too rapidly after one another.. I'm thinking that some settimeout could do it, but I don't know how or where to put it in my code:

```
var istyping = false;
var wastyping = false;

chatfield.keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) {

        function typesignal(state) {
            channel.send(JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
                type: 'typing',
                message: state
            }));
        }

        if (chatfield.val()) {

            istyping = true;

                if (wastyping==false) {
                    typesignal(1);
                    wastyping = true;
                }

        } else {

            istyping = false;

                if (wastyping==true) {
                    typesignal(0);
                    wastyping = false;
                }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might call this 'throttling' and I've used it a bunch on things like autocomplete dropdowns so you don't kill the server on every keystroke. The JS standard library lets you clear timeouts, and also returns an id when setTimeout is called. So you can use this id to clear the timeout (prevent the callback from being called within the time period) if the function is called again within a certain period of time. So for example:

```
var timeId;

function throttle(callback, ms) {
    if (timeId) {
      clearTimeout(timeId);
    }

    timeId = setTimeout(callback, ms)
}

chatfield.keyup(function(e) {
  throttle(your_fn, 500);
});
```

In case it's not clear, the setTimeout executes a function after a certain period of time, specified in milliseconds as the second parameter. So, if I call setTimeout(function(){},300) that function will be called after 300 ms. And I can also say, "cancel" that original request. So if I get another request before the first one has fired, just cancel it and start over. That's the pattern I was trying to describe above :-)

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow :-)

Comment: Thanx. I hope you (or someone) can help ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'd do this

```
chatfield.keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) {

        function typesignal(state) {
            channel.send(JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
                type: 'typing',
                message: state
            }));
        }

        if (chatfield.val()) {

            istyping = true;

                if (wastyping==false) {
                    typesignal(1);
                    wastyping = true;
                }

        } else {

            istyping = false;

                if (wastyping==true) {
                    typesignal(0);
                    wastyping = false;
                }

        }
    }
function doNothing() { 
}
setTimeout("doNothing()",1000);
});
```